# Error while attempting to create an .ipa file in Xcode 7

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods, ios9, xcode7, ipa

I'm using a cocoa pod file (pod 'Konotor', '~> 3.6') in my project. Now unable to make archive. I'm using konotor library and added in my project but it's not working:

[image]

Has anyone else faced this issue and know how to resolve it?

Additionally, how can I remove this file from my project so that I can create an .ipa file?

Comment: I tried cleaning up your question for clarification. Read it over and make sure it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these solutions

#### Solution 1

run the command from the terminal in your project home directory

```
pod install
```

It will update your existing pods, then try to create you ipa

#### Solution 2

Remove `CFBundleSupportedPlatforms` key/value pair from the `info.plist` file of `KonotorModels.bundle` and the try to create the ipa

[image]